# angular 10 - alternative for webviews

Tags: angular, webview

I'm creating an Angular 10 web app and a NativeScript Angular mobile app. Webviews are a feature available for mobile apps. My question is, what's the alternative for a webview in web app? I have to load an external HTML page where some business logic happens and on clicking a button in that external page, an event is triggered and a value is returned.

This is the code of the external page

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnDone").click(function () {
            var oWebViewInterface = window.nsWebViewInterface
            oWebViewInterface.emit('returnVariable', "0");

        });
        $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
            var oWebViewInterface = window.nsWebViewInterface
            oWebViewInterface.emit('returnVariable', "1");

        });
    });
```

I want to handle the value returned on these button clicks in an angular component

This is the sample of my angular component from where I'm loading the external URL

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({ selector: 'app-sample', templateUrl: 'sample.component.html' })
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

    public paymentUrl: string = 'external-url.com';
    constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onBtnClickinANgularWebApp() {
        this.document.location.href = this.paymentUrl;
    }
}
```